# How to remove an element from a list without using remove function in LISP

Tags: error-handling, lisp

```
  (defun my_remove(e list1 list2)
  (if (null list1)
   nil
  ((setf x car(list1))
    (if (!= x e)
    ((my_append  e list2 )
    (setf y cdr(list1))
    (my_remove(e y list2)))

    ((setf y cdr(list1))
    (my_remove(e y list2))
     )))))
```

I am trying to write a function to remove an element from a list but i am getting an     error that "It should be lambada function" and I don't know that my code is correct or wrong.

Comment: proper formatting will help a lot (this isn't a snarky comment;  it's hard to tell the syntax from parens alone—indentation matters!)

Comment: I m beginner here, I don't know proper indentation, I tried whatever i have written above

Comment: It will help you greatly if you can use an editor that's Lisp-aware, such as Emacs or one built into an IDE (e.g., Lispworks' editor).

Comment: `vim` is also aware of Lisp syntax. Are you learning from a class or a textbook? There are some very fundamental syntax problems with the code. A few Lisp example functions would make that clear. I think you should sort through some of that off-line, and then make another attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problems with your code

There are a few problems with your code.  First, let's look at it with standard indentation

```
(defun my_remove(e list1 list2)
  (if (null list1)
      nil
      ((setf x car(list1))                   ; (i)
       (if (!= x e)
           ((my_append  e list2 )            ; (ii)
            (setf y cdr(list1))              ; (iii)
            (my_remove(e y list2)))          ; (iv)
           ((setf y cdr(list1))              ; (v)
            (my_remove(e y list2)))))))      ; (vi)
```

Each of the marked lines has a problem.  The syntax for a function call in Lisp is

```
(function argument…)
```

That means that in your line `(i)`, you're trying to call a function named `(setf x car(list1))` with an argument `(if (!= x e) …)`.  Of course, that's not the name of a function, and I suspect that even if it was, you didn't want to call it with the argument `(if (!= x e) …)`.  Similarly

```
(setf x car (list1))
```

Is trying to to set `x` to the value of the value of a variable `car` (and there isn't one), and then assign a new value to the place `(list1)`.  Since the syntax for a function call is `(function argument…)`, you want instead:

```
(setf x (car list1))
```

If you're trying to sequence forms, you might consider using [`cond`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw60/CLHS/Body/m_cond.htm), in which you can provide multiple forms, or `progn` (see [In Common Lisp, why do multi-expression bodies of (if) statements require (progn)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526173/in-common-lisp-why-do-multi-expression-bodies-of-if-statements-require-progn)).

For instance, instead of

```
           ((my_append  e list2 )            ; (ii)
            (setf y cdr(list1))              ; (iii)
            (my_remove(e y list2)))          ; (iv)
```

you probably want

```
           (progn
            (my_append  e list2 )            ; (ii)
            (setf y cdr(list1))              ; (iii)
            (my_remove(e y list2)))          ; (iv)
```

You'll have some problems with that, too, though.  In `(iii)` and `(iv)`, you'll need to use `(cdr list1)` and `(my_remove e y list2)`, as discussed above, but you also have the problem that you're evaluating `(ii)` and `(iii)`, but you're discarding the value.

### A simplified approach

I think it might be to your benefit if you think about a simple definition of `my-remove`.  In general, a list is either the empty list `()` or a cons cell whose car is the first element of the list and whose cdr is the rest of the list.  You can use a definition like this, then:

- remove(x,list)

  - if list is empty, then return list (it's empty, so it certainly doesn't contain x)
  - if list is not empty, then

    - if the first element of the list is x, then return remove(x,rest(list))
    - else, the first element of the list is not x, so return a new list whose first element is the first element of list, and whose rest is remove(x,rest(list)).

In code, that looks like:

```
(defun my-remove (element list)
  (if (endp list)
      list
      (if (eql element (first list))
          (my-remove element (rest list))
          (list* (first list)
                 (my-remove element (rest list))))))
```

```
CL-USER> (my-remove 1 '(1 2 3 1 2 3))
(2 3 2 3)
```

Those nested `if`s look a bit ugly, and you might want to use `cond` here, even though you don't need the multiple expression bodies that it permits:

```
(defun my-remove (element list)
  (cond
    ((endp list)
     list)
    ((eql element (first list))
     (my-remove element (rest list)))
    (t
     (list* (first list) (my-remove element (rest list))))))
```

Since a `cond` clause with no body whose test form evaluates to true returns the value of the test form, you can even make that last clause a bit simpler:

```
(defun my-remove (element list)
  (cond
    ((endp list) list)
    ((eql element (first list)) (my-remove element (rest list)))
    ((list* (first list) (my-remove element (rest list))))))
```

Comment: sorry, actually i was trying to set the first element of 'list1' in 'x'

Comment: What is list* and
what is endp ?

Comment: @user39495 In this it can be replaced by `cons`, but `list*` is like `list` except the last argument is the tail of the resulting list. eg `(list* 1 2 '(3 4 5)) ; ==> (1 2 3 4 5)`. `endp` is a synonym for `null`.

Comment: @user39495 Sylwester's answer is correct. I like to use `endp`/`first`/`rest`/`list*` to emphasize that we're working with lists here, rather than trees of `cons` cells.  These questions, though, are easily answered with a quick Google search, or even more specifically, a search on lispdoc.com, e.g., for [endp](http://lispdoc.com/?q=endp&search=Basic+search).  `list*` is a bit harder to search for, but it's on the same page as [list](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_list_.htm).